# On Scroll Add Class One by One

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, scroll

I am trying to add a class to a group of elements one by one then reverse but not removing it from the first item in the group.

Here is a fiddle of my HTML and CSS. https://jsfiddle.net/316n1xmL/

```js
// Scroll Direction Plugin Move Later to own file

!function(a){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],a):"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=a:a(jQuery)}(function(a){function b(b){var g=b||window.event,h=i.call(arguments,1),j=0,l=0,m=0,n=0,o=0,p=0;if(b=a.event.fix(g),b.type="mousewheel","detail"in g&&(m=-1*g.detail),"wheelDelta"in g&&(m=g.wheelDelta),"wheelDeltaY"in g&&(m=g.wheelDeltaY),"wheelDeltaX"in g&&(l=-1*g.wheelDeltaX),"axis"in g&&g.axis===g.HORIZONTAL_AXIS&&(l=-1*m,m=0),j=0===m?l:m,"deltaY"in g&&(m=-1*g.deltaY,j=m),"deltaX"in g&&(l=g.deltaX,0===m&&(j=-1*l)),0!==m||0!==l){if(1===g.deltaMode){var q=a.data(this,"mousewheel-line-height");j*=q,m*=q,l*=q}else if(2===g.deltaMode){var r=a.data(this,"mousewheel-page-height");j*=r,m*=r,l*=r}if(n=Math.max(Math.abs(m),Math.abs(l)),(!f||f>n)&&(f=n,d(g,n)&&(f/=40)),d(g,n)&&(j/=40,l/=40,m/=40),j=Math[j>=1?"floor":"ceil"](j/f),l=Math[l>=1?"floor":"ceil"](l/f),m=Math[m>=1?"floor":"ceil"](m/f),k.settings.normalizeOffset&&this.getBoundingClientRect){var s=this.getBoundingClientRect();o=b.clientX-s.left,p=b.clientY-s.top}return b.deltaX=l,b.deltaY=m,b.deltaFactor=f,b.offsetX=o,b.offsetY=p,b.deltaMode=0,h.unshift(b,j,l,m),e&&clearTimeout(e),e=setTimeout(c,200),(a.event.dispatch||a.event.handle).apply(this,h)}}function c(){f=null}function d(a,b){return k.settings.adjustOldDeltas&&"mousewheel"===a.type&&b%120===0}var e,f,g=["wheel","mousewheel","DOMMouseScroll","MozMousePixelScroll"],h="onwheel"in document||document.documentMode>=9?["wheel"]:["mousewheel","DomMouseScroll","MozMousePixelScroll"],i=Array.prototype.slice;if(a.event.fixHooks)for(var j=g.length;j;)a.event.fixHooks[g[--j]]=a.event.mouseHooks;var k=a.event.special.mousewheel={version:"3.1.12",setup:function(){if(this.addEventListener)for(var c=h.length;c;)this.addEventListener(h[--c],b,!1);else this.onmousewheel=b;a.data(this,"mousewheel-line-height",k.getLineHeight(this)),a.data(this,"mousewheel-page-height",k.getPageHeight(this))},teardown:function(){if(this.removeEventListener)for(var c=h.length;c;)this.removeEventListener(h[--c],b,!1);else this.onmousewheel=null;a.removeData(this,"mousewheel-line-height"),a.removeData(this,"mousewheel-page-height")},getLineHeight:function(b){var c=a(b),d=c["offsetParent"in a.fn?"offsetParent":"parent"]();return d.length||(d=a("body")),parseInt(d.css("fontSize"),10)||parseInt(c.css("fontSize"),10)||16},getPageHeight:function(b){return a(b).height()},settings:{adjustOldDeltas:!0,normalizeOffset:!0}};a.fn.extend({mousewheel:function(a){return a?this.bind("mousewheel",a):this.trigger("mousewheel")},unmousewheel:function(a){return this.unbind("mousewheel",a)}})});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).mousewheel(function(turn, delta) {

    var tiles = $('.list-tile');
    if (delta == 1) {

    } else {
      $(tiles).next().not('animate-up').addClass('animate-up');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.hero-list {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  touch-action: pan-x;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hero-list .hero-list-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 901;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hero-list .hero-list-container .list-tile {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.hero-list .hero-list-container .list-tile:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: green;
}

.hero-list .hero-list-container .list-tile:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.hero-list .hero-list-container .list-tile .module-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transform: translate3d(0, -20%, 0) scale(1.5);
}

.hero-list .hero-list-container .list-tile.animate-up {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0) scale(1) !important;
}

.hero-list .hero-list-container .list-tile.animate-up .module-background {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0) scale(1) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero-list">
  <div class="hero-list-container">
    <div class="list-tile animate-up">
      <div class="module-background" style="background-image: url('https://thomasstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/wp-media/2017/11/tech-background.png');    background-size: cover;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="list-tile">
      <div class="module-background" style="background-image: url('https://thomasstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/wp-media/2017/11/tech-background.png'); background-size: cover;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="list-tile">
      <div class="module-background" style="background-image: url('https://thomasstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/wp-media/2017/11/tech-background.png');    background-size: cover;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="list-tile">
      <div class="module-background" style="background-image: url('https://thomasstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/wp-media/2017/11/tech-background.png');    background-size: cover;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Right now on scroll down it adds the class to all the list-tiles which I know why it is doing that. I got close once but it was clunky.

I tried putting the items in an array which seemed to work but actually trying to target a specific position in the array returned undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wrap titles in the jquery selector because it is already a jQuery collection. Next() isn't the function you want because it is getting the siblings of each element in the collection (which in this case is already all of your target elements).

I changed the code to filter out the ones that were already set as animate-up first, and then used eq(0) to pick off the first element in that filtered collection.

Note that the mousewheel event is being fired very rapidly, so you are probably going to need to add in a means of throttling to get the effect you actually want I imagine.

```js
// Scroll Direction Plugin Move Later to own file

!function(a){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],a):"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=a:a(jQuery)}(function(a){function b(b){var g=b||window.event,h=i.call(arguments,1),j=0,l=0,m=0,n=0,o=0,p=0;if(b=a.event.fix(g),b.type="mousewheel","detail"in g&&(m=-1*g.detail),"wheelDelta"in g&&(m=g.wheelDelta),"wheelDeltaY"in g&&(m=g.wheelDeltaY),"wheelDeltaX"in g&&(l=-1*g.wheelDeltaX),"axis"in g&&g.axis===g.HORIZONTAL_AXIS&&(l=-1*m,m=0),j=0===m?l:m,"deltaY"in g&&(m=-1*g.deltaY,j=m),"deltaX"in g&&(l=g.deltaX,0===m&&(j=-1*l)),0!==m||0!==l){if(1===g.deltaMode){var q=a.data(this,"mousewheel-line-height");j*=q,m*=q,l*=q}else if(2===g.deltaMode){var r=a.data(this,"mousewheel-page-height");j*=r,m*=r,l*=r}if(n=Math.max(Math.abs(m),Math.abs(l)),(!f||f>n)&&(f=n,d(g,n)&&(f/=40)),d(g,n)&&(j/=40,l/=40,m/=40),j=Math[j>=1?"floor":"ceil"](j/f),l=Math[l>=1?"floor":"ceil"](l/f),m=Math[m>=1?"floor":"ceil"](m/f),k.settings.normalizeOffset&&this.getBoundingClientRect){var s=this.getBoundingClientRect();o=b.clientX-s.left,p=b.clientY-s.top}return b.deltaX=l,b.deltaY=m,b.deltaFactor=f,b.offsetX=o,b.offsetY=p,b.deltaMode=0,h.unshift(b,j,l,m),e&&clearTimeout(e),e=setTimeout(c,200),(a.event.dispatch||a.event.handle).apply(this,h)}}function c(){f=null}function d(a,b){return k.settings.adjustOldDeltas&&"mousewheel"===a.type&&b%120===0}var e,f,g=["wheel","mousewheel","DOMMouseScroll","MozMousePixelScroll"],h="onwheel"in document||document.documentMode>=9?["wheel"]:["mousewheel","DomMouseScroll","MozMousePixelScroll"],i=Array.prototype.slice;if(a.event.fixHooks)for(var j=g.length;j;)a.event.fixHooks[g[--j]]=a.event.mouseHooks;var k=a.event.special.mousewheel={version:"3.1.12",setup:function(){if(this.addEventListener)for(var c=h.length;c;)this.addEventListener(h[--c],b,!1);else this.onmousewheel=b;a.data(this,"mousewheel-line-height",k.getLineHeight(this)),a.data(this,"mousewheel-page-height",k.getPageHeight(this))},teardown:function(){if(this.removeEventListener)for(var c=h.length;c;)this.removeEventListener(h[--c],b,!1);else this.onmousewheel=null;a.removeData(this,"mousewheel-line-height"),a.removeData(this,"mousewheel-page-height")},getLineHeight:function(b){var c=a(b),d=c["offsetParent"in a.fn?"offsetParent":"parent"]();return d.length||(d=a("body")),parseInt(d.css("fontSize"),10)||parseInt(c.css("fontSize"),10)||16},getPageHeight:function(b){return a(b).height()},settings:{adjustOldDeltas:!0,normalizeOffset:!0}};a.fn.extend({mousewheel:function(a){return a?this.bind("mousewheel",a):this.trigger("mousewheel")},unmousewheel:function(a){return this.unbind("mousewheel",a)}})});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).mousewheel(function(turn, delta) {

    var tiles = $('.list-tile');
    if (delta == 1) {
      tiles.filter('.animate-up').last().removeClass('animate-up');
    } else {
      tiles.not('.animate-up').eq(0).addClass('animate-up');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.hero-list {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  touch-action: pan-x;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hero-list .hero-list-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 901;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hero-list .hero-list-container .list-tile {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.hero-list .hero-list-container .list-tile:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: green;
}

.hero-list .hero-list-container .list-tile:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.hero-list .hero-list-container .list-tile .module-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transform: translate3d(0, -20%, 0) scale(1.5);
}

.hero-list .hero-list-container .list-tile.animate-up {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0) scale(1) !important;
}

.hero-list .hero-list-container .list-tile.animate-up .module-background {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0) scale(1) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero-list">
  <div class="hero-list-container">
    <div class="list-tile animate-up">
      <div class="module-background" style="background-image: url('https://thomasstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/wp-media/2017/11/tech-background.png');    background-size: cover;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="list-tile">
      <div class="module-background" style="background-image: url('https://thomasstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/wp-media/2017/11/tech-background.png'); background-size: cover;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="list-tile">
      <div class="module-background" style="background-image: url('https://thomasstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/wp-media/2017/11/tech-background.png');    background-size: cover;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="list-tile">
      <div class="module-background" style="background-image: url('https://thomasstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/wp-media/2017/11/tech-background.png');    background-size: cover;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked, how easy would it be to reverse it so that it removes on scroll up?

Comment: pretty easily. Just need to filter tiles for that class and then get the last one. I amended the snippet. If you want to keep the first one from animating out you could do a check for it before removing the animate-up class. Either give that element an id attribute and filter out that id as well, or some other approach.

Comment: Would adding an extra class to it work? That way even if the animate up is removed it stays?

You are also correct about the scrolling needing a threshold. Thanks so much!

Comment: I got it I just added .not('.first') to the first tile. Now to figure out the mouse scroll threshold!

Comment: maybe this helps https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/